# Declare an array of ordered pairs where the first element of the pair is a positive integer and the second is the value of a function such as Sine

Tags: arrays

I want to declare a array of ordered pairs where the first element of the pair is a positive integer and the second is the value of math function, such as the Sine. I could set the values with a loop in a class, but it seems I may be able to do it with the declaration. Is that possible; what are some suggestions for the syntax?

Comment: When you say `value of a function` are you referring to value of sine of the number or a pointer to a function?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: How about `someType someArray[xxx, 2]`?  Of course, initializing it is another matter.

Comment: I did one of those a long time ago because the sin function was too slow.  If you get your Radians hat on for full circle I think you'll get your answer.  I hard coded mine to be 256 entries so I was able to declare it.  The declaration depends on the language.

Comment: Using Java, working with Eclipse.